# How to make and AutoUpdate readonly after another autoupdate input value set to null?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have 2 AutoUpdates.  The first one is meant to receive country names.  Then it does the autocomplete.

After the item is selected a second autocomplete is set to readonly="false" by EL inside the XHTML.

It works fine until I go back to the first AutoComplete and empty the current value.  The desired behavior is to clear the second autocomplete and makes it readonly="true", but it is not happening.  What happens is that second autocomplete remains with its value with readonly="false".

Howe to fix this?

My XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head></h:head>
<ui:debug rendered="true" hotkey="X" />
<body>
    <h:form id="searchAddressForm" prependId="true">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel for="autoCompleteCountry" value="Country" />

            <p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteCountry"
                forceSelection="true"
                dropdown="true"
                var="selectedCountry" 
                itemValue="#{selectedCountry}"
                itemLabel="#{selectedCountry.nicename}"
                value="#{addressReadController.selectedCountry}" 
                minQueryLength="3" queryDelay="1000"
                completeMethod="#{addressReadController.completeCountry}"
                converter="#{countryConverter}">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{addressReadController.handleCountrySelect}" update="msgs autoCompleteState"/>
            </p:autoComplete>

            <p:outputLabel for="autoCompleteState" value="State" />
            <p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteState" forceSelection="true" disabled="#{empty addressReadController.selectedCountry}"
                dropdown="true"
                var="selectedState" 
                itemValue="#{selectedState}"
                itemLabel="#{selectedState.name}"
                value="#{addressReadController.selectedState}" 
                minQueryLength="3" queryDelay="1000"
                completeMethod="#{addressReadController.completeState}"
                converter="#{stateConverter}">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                    listener="#{addressReadController.handleStateSelect}" update="msgs"/>
            </p:autoComplete>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controler

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;

import my.package.ejb.AddressEJB;
import my.package.ejb.AddressTypeEJB;
import my.package.ejb.CityEJB;
import my.package.ejb.CountryEJB;
import my.package.ejb.SiteTypeEJB;
import my.package.ejb.StateEJB;
import my.package.entity.AddressType;
import my.package.entity.City;
import my.package.entity.Country;
import my.package.entity.SiteType;
import my.package.entity.State;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class AddressReadController implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2224053530553846981L;

    @EJB
    private CountryEJB countryEJB;

    @EJB
    private StateEJB stateEJB;

    @EJB
    private CityEJB cityEJB;

    @EJB
    private SiteTypeEJB siteTypeEJB;

    @EJB
    private AddressTypeEJB addressTypeEJB;

    @EJB
    private AddressEJB addressEJB;

    private Country selectedCountry = null;

    private State selectedState = null;

    private AddressType selectedAddressType = null;

    private City selectedCity = null;

    private SiteType selectedSiteType = null;

    private String selectedComplement = null;

    private Integer selectedNumber = null;

    private String selectedStreetName = null;

    private String selectedZipCode = null;

    /*
     * Begin of AJAX event handlers
     */

    public void handleCountrySelect(SelectEvent e) {
        selectedCountry = (Country) e.getObject();
        selectedState = null; 
        addMessage(selectedCountry.getNicename() + " selected");
    }

    public void handleCountryUnSelect(UnselectEvent e) {
        selectedCountry = (Country) e.getObject();
        addMessage(selectedCountry.getNicename() + " selected");
    }

    public void handleStateSelect(SelectEvent e) {
        selectedState = (State) e.getObject();
        addMessage(selectedState.getName() + " selected");
    }

    public void handleStateUnSelect(UnselectEvent e) {
        selectedState = (State) e.getObject();
        addMessage(selectedState.getName() + " selected");
    }

    public void phaseListener(PhaseEvent e) {
        List<FacesMessage> messages = e.getFacesContext().getMessageList();
        System.out.println(messages.size());
    }

    public List<Country> completeCountry(String query) {
        return countryEJB.findByStartingChars(query);
    }

    public List<State> completeState(String query) {
        return stateEJB.findByStartingChars(query, selectedCountry);
    }

    public void addMessage(String summary) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                summary, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }   
    /*
     * End of AJAX event handlers
     */

    public State getSelectedState() {
        return selectedState;
    }

    public void setSelectedState(State selectedState) {
        this.selectedState = selectedState;
    }

    public void onCountryChange() {
        this.selectedState = new State();
        this.selectedCity = new City();
    }

    public String getSelectedComplement() {
        return selectedComplement;
    }

    public void setSelectedComplement(String selectedComplement) {
        this.selectedComplement = selectedComplement;
    }

    public Integer getSelectedNumber() {
        return selectedNumber;
    }

    public void setSelectedNumber(Integer selectedNumber) {
        this.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;
    }

    public Country getSelectedCountry() {
        return selectedCountry;
    }

    public void setSelectedCountry(Country selectedCountry) {
        this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    }

    public City getSelectedCity() {
        return selectedCity;
    }

    public void setSelectedCity(City selectedCity) {
        this.selectedCity = selectedCity;
    }

    public AddressType getSelectedAddressType() {
        return selectedAddressType;
    }

    public void setSelectedAddressType(AddressType selectedAddressType) {
        this.selectedAddressType = selectedAddressType;
    }

    public SiteType getSelectedSiteType() {
        return selectedSiteType;
    }

    public void setSelectedSiteType(SiteType selectedSiteType) {
        this.selectedSiteType = selectedSiteType;
    }

    public String getSelectedStreetName() {
        return selectedStreetName;
    }

    public void setSelectedStreetName(String selectedStreetName) {
        this.selectedStreetName = selectedStreetName;
    }

    public String getSelectedZipCode() {
        return selectedZipCode;
    }

    public void setSelectedZipCode(String selectedZipCode) {
        this.selectedZipCode = selectedZipCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide PF version

Comment: Next time please provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What updates 2nd `p:autoComplete` is `<p:ajax event="itemSelect" .../>` but this action involves item selection. When you go back and clear input, then you didn't choose any item, so the action won't invoke and won't update 2nd `p:autoComplete`.

This little script worked for me. What it does is - it triggers `itemSelect` event after input loses focus, but only when it is empty:

```
<script>
$(document).on("blur", "#searchAddressForm\\:autoCompleteCountry_input", function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).trigger("itemSelect");
    }
});
</script>
```

Notice `_input` after id, this is input generated from PrimeFaces as a child of `span` generated by `p:autoComplete` component.

EDIT:

Or add `onblur` attribute to your autocomplete and invoke function.

```
<p:autoComplete id="autoCompleteCountry" onblur="itemSelectionOnClear(this)" />

<script>
    function itemSelectionOnClear(autoComplete) {
        if($(autoComplete).val().length == 0) {
            $(autoComplete).trigger("itemSelect");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tested in PrimeFaces 5.2